# How do I animate (slide in) a RecyclerView's item's entrance?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Basically I want something like [this (at the 30 second mark)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8TXgCzxEnw#t=30)

I want my items to slide in sequentially once the activity starts.

I tried Googling. I found nothing that I can understand. I'm still getting my way around this crazy world of developing apps for Android.

Thanks.

Comment: 404 Page Not Found....your link

Comment: @AmarbirSingh I edited his post but he hasn't approved that yet. Anyway here is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8TXgCzxEnw#t=30 he was talking about.

Comment: @Amarbir Sorry for that. I already edited the link.

Comment: You can use this library https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators and add your items with a short delay, for example with a Handler.

Answer (score 18):

Add animation on recyclerView like this

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

        AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

        Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        animation.setDuration(500);
        set.addAnimation(animation);

        animation = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f
        );
        animation.setDuration(100);
        set.addAnimation(animation);

        controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.5f);

        adapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(poetNameSetGets, this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer!

Comment: Do you know how can I use that animation when I clear all the data from the recyclerview?

Answer (score 6):

You need to run animation inside the RecyclerView's Adapter `onBindViewHolder` method.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    runEnterAnimation(viewHolder.itemView);
}

private void runEnterAnimation(View view) {
        view.setTranslationY(Utils.getScreenHeight(context));
        view.animate()
                .translationY(0)
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(3.f))
                .setDuration(700)
                .start();
    }
}
```

More info here http://frogermcs.github.io/Instagram-with-Material-Design-concept-is-getting-real/ (look at the FeedAdapter)

Comment: You need to provide setTranslationY with screen height. Check here to get height http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels

Comment: Works great. One more thing though. How do I animate them sequentially?

Comment: Don't they animate sequentially now? Because they should.

Comment: They're not. All items slide in at the same time.

Comment: Can't give you the detailed answer in the comments. Post another question.