# How to implement Slide-in and Slide-out animation on entire Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, gridlayoutmanager

I have an RecyclerView customized as a calendar using GridLayoutManager. When I swipe the RecyclerView the data in the RecyclerView changes to reflect that the month has changed. I want to animate this swipe action. The current month view of the RecyclerView should slide out and the new month RecyclerView should slide in? The animation must be on the entire RecyclerView and not on a single item.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I animate (slide in) a RecyclerView's item's entrance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169661/how-do-i-animate-slide-in-a-recyclerviews-items-entrance)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444739/how-to-add-recyclerview-slide-in-animation-for-new-item

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361255/recyclerview-slidein-animation-on-activity-start

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181307/how-to-animate-recyclerview-on-scroll-like-google-plus-google-newsstand

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewPager and create FragmentPagerAdapter

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html